# URL Split and remove

Tags: c#, url, uri

I'm doing some conversions from `VB` to `C#` and stuck on getting some items for the URI.

My legacy code is as follows

```
strURL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
Dim URL As String() = strURL.Split("?")
strURL = URL(0).Replace("index.aspx", "")
```

Now I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to pick up any `querystrings` which I set in some option drop boxes. The URL I'm getting from the request.url is www.testsite.com/test/courses

```
strURL = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
string[] URL = strURL.Split(new string[] { "?" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
strURL = URL[0].Replace("index.aspx", "");
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample string for: `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;`?

Comment: Why do you mess with the `AbsoluteUri` property if you could easily get the query string from [the `Query` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.query.aspx)?

Comment: Isn't that `VB.NET` ?